# What kind of screws for a strike plate in a metal/steel door frame?

Tags: door-frame

I live in a house that was built in the 1950s. The door frame was made of metal/steel. Since I noticed that the strike plate is missing, I'd like to install a new plate. My question is -- what kind of screws should I be using? Machine screws? If you look at the photo below, the mounting holes look like threaded holes. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: the photo is not clear enough to determine if the holes are threaded ..... you are the only one that can decide what kind of screws to use

Comment: @jsotola Good point. Since I have a bunch of machine screws lying around (e.g., 4-40s, 6-32s, 8-32s, 10-32s, etc.), I found out that the threaded holes are for 8-32 machine screws after trying a few sizes. I need to order 8-32 machine screws with a flat head because what I have currently are socket head-cap screws.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, metal frames use machine screws, not self-tapping screws.

I’d order a plastic “strike box dust cup” too.

Btw, those existing metal tabs with the screw holes in them are made to be adjusted slightly. I’d be careful moving them, because the screws may not align if you move them too much. However, if the flat head screws do not “seat” properly in the strike plate, you can adjust those tabs.

Comment: Instead of working with the strike plate that comes with my door knob, I am thinking of starting with a (thin) piece of aluminum. The center-to-center distance of my threaded holes is 1.5", while the standard distance is 1 5/8" ~ 1.63". I should be able to drill two clear holes and shape the aluminum plate using my Dremel tool (and a vise).

Comment: Seems like that would be difficult to align the screw holes EXACTLY.  You can buy new strike plates at hardware stores.

Comment: My thinking was to make my own strike plate from a blank piece of aluminum